# Blueimp jQuery File Upload - upload long lists problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-upload-file-plugin

When I selected 100 files to upload in the [demo website][1] and then clicked on "Start upload" button some of those files start uploading and the rest of them got stuck in "Processing..."!

I have the same problem in my local version too and I have tried to find some option to keep "Start Upload" button disabled until all the files loaded correctly but I couldn't find it! does anybody know how can I handle this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I found the solution, with the help of [callbacks](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#processing-callback-options).

First of all, I used **fileuploadadd** to count how many files user selected to be upload:

```
      'fileuploadadd' => 'function(e, data) {
                            $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                              uploadListCounter++;
                            });
                            $("#upload-loading").show();
                            $("#upload-file_name-fileupload").hide()
                      }'
```

Then in **fileuploadprocessdone** I checked if it processed all the selected files:

```
      'fileuploadprocessdone' => 'function(e, data) {
                        uploadListProcessedCounter++;
                        $("#upload-loading").text("Please wait, loading " + uploadListProcessedCounter + "/" + uploadListCounter);
                        if( uploadListProcessedCounter == uploadListCounter ) {
                          $("#upload-file_name-fileupload").show();
                          $("#upload-loading").hide();
                        }
                    }'
```